# Stop a number of httpd processes starting on MacBook Pro running Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, mamp

I am running MAMP and noticed that a number of httpd processes were running in Activity Monitor.

I had 24 separate processes running at one time. The users were daemon, root and _www. I also have zend running php, lighttpd and mysqld even though I uninstalled

Does anyone know how to stop some of these processes starting up in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove autostart of apache on macosx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065288/how-to-remove-autostart-of-apache-on-macosx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you can turn off or stop services from starting up every time your machine starts by looking in the following folders:

- /Library/LaunchAgents
- /Library/LaunchDaemons
- /Library/StartupItems

That sorted everything out.